# Контекст данных Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть 1 вопрос касательно работы контекста в Asp.net core. Вроде бы, через зависимость передается объект контекста:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

public MyContext db;
public HomeController(MyContext context)
{
    db = context;
}
```

Если не ошибаюсь, контекст данных должен быть пустым (не засунется же туда вся база данных). Когда я передал в представление контекст `return View(db.Users)`, то через точку останова посмотрел, что он был уже заполнен всеми данными из таблицы `Users`. Разве он не должен быть пуст? 
И еще вопрос. Когда я хочу получить данные из БД:
public DbSet Users { get; set; }

```
IQueryable test=db.Users.Where(p => p.Age==18)
IQueryable test1=db.Users.Where(p => p.Age==18)
```

Сначала мы обратимся к БД. на второй такой же запрос он уже обратиться не к БД, а к контексту (данные о юзерах 18ти лет сохранены ведь в контексте)? Верно?

Comment: `через точку останова посмотрел, что он был уже заполнен всеми данными из таблицы Users. Разве он не должен быть пуст` контекст поддерживает ленивую загрузку, то есть загрузку данных в момент, когда они требуются. Вы в отладчике запросили данные от контекста, он сбегал в бд, получил данные и вам показал.

Comment: `Сначала мы обратимся к БД. на второй такой же запрос он уже обратиться не к БД, а к контексту` это требует проверки (которую вы и сами можете сделать), но я бы не рассчитывал на подобное.

Comment: @tym32167 Не подскажете, какую проверку надо выполнить?

Comment: Само по себе вот это выражение `IQueryable test=db.Users.Where(p => p.Age==18)` не обращается в бд, чтобы обратиться в бд, надо перечислить ваш test, `foreach(var item in test)..`

Comment: Проверку простую - полключитесь к вашей бд профайлером или подпишитесь на логи контекста, чтобы видеть все запросы между контекстом и бд.

Comment: Отключите LazyLoading, вечно с ней какие-то сюрпризы.